# Reading from file using fgets

Tags: c, fgets, file-read

I am reading from file of format

```
1 32 43 23
32 43
123 43 54 243 
123 2222
2
```

Here is my code snippet.

```
string[100];
while(!feof(fp))
    fgets(string,100,fp)
```

Now, when I put every string, in the last string I am getting repetition and some more ambiguities (like something else also gets printed say 123 or so).

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Is there an end-of-line `\n` character at the end of the last line in your file?

Comment: Post your full actual code, this shouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to check the return value of [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). If a read has been successful, `fgets` returns the pointer to the buffer that you passed to it (i.e. `string` in your example). If the End-of-File is encountered and no characters have been read, `fgets` returns `NULL`.

Try this:

```
char string[100];
while(fgets(string, 100, fp)) {
    printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

Comment: Why would you test with feof if fgets does so?

Comment: @ManuelReis You are right, `feof` test s unnecessary (edited).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was having an existential crisis for a second.

Comment: The `\n` inside issued by the `printf` is not necessary, as it already comes via `fgets()` from inside the file (if around).

Comment: Having fgets() return value assumed to be 0, this code works. Generally NULL is not necessarily 0, it is generally `(void*)0`. Code is more readable, if you check with NULL

Answer (score 7):

The `eof` is only reached *after* you have attempted to read from a file that is at the end. You have to use the return value of `fgets` instead (which returns `NULL` on eof or error and the pointer it is given otherwise):

```
char string[100];
while(fgets(string, 100, fp))
    // do stuff with string
```

Checking the return value like this will cause you never to hit the eof inside the body of the loop, like the other one, instead of in the condition.