# Having problems transferring data from my second txt file to my second character array using command line arguments

Tags: c, string, file, io, command-line-arguments

The exact problem that I am having is that we were assigned to make a program that had 2 command line arguments, both being text files. The code that I have for arg[1] works fine, it reads in the text file and stores it into an array. Once it is stored into the array called key it goes through a loop that only leaves alpha characters and makes uppercase change to lowercase. Once again this works fine when i test it and print out the final array called key. When I use the same code for arg[2] the first loop (while(!feof(file2))) does not even copy the contents of the other text file into the array called plain correctly. It copies all the content but adds ▒ at the end when i print out the plain array to test to see if I have all the characters in there before running it through the loop that only leaves alphacharacters in it. If I switch the order of the files when I enter them in the terminal then the second file works fine with the arg[1] code but then the other file does not work with the arg[2] code. I'm using mobaxterm so I enter it like "./a.out k1.txt p1.txt" without the quotations of course. I also commented out the code that strips the nonalpha characters in arg[2] just to try and figure out why the while loop before it is not storing the file contents correctly.

Here are the contents of the text files

k1.txt (instead of a space imagine it goes to the next line):

bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb

p1.txt:

"If you find that you're spending almost all your time on theory, start turning some attention to practical things; it will improve your theories. If you find that you're spending almost all your time on practice, start turning some attention to theoretical things; it will improve your practice." - Donald Knuth

This is an encryption assignment by the way and k1 is the key and p1 is the plain text.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    printf( "\ncommandline arguments including program name:\n\n");
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < argc; i++ ) {
                      printf( "argument %d: %s\n", i, argv[ i ] );
    }
    printf( "\n");

    char* fname = argv[ 1 ];
    FILE *file = fopen( fname, "r" );
    char key[512];
    int x,y, z=0;

    if ( file == 0 )
    {
                      printf( "Could not open file\n" );
    } else {
                      printf( "File opened successfully\n" );

                      while(!feof(file))
                         {
                            fscanf(file, "%c", &key[z]);
                            z++;
                         }fscanf(file, "%c", &key[z]);

                            for(x=0; key[x] != '\0'; x++)
                            {
                               while(!((key[x] >= 'a' && key[x] <= 'z') || (key[x] >= 'A' && key[x] <= 'Z') || key[x] == '\0'))
                               {
                                  for(y=x; key[y] != '\0'; ++y)
                                     {
                                        key[y]=key[y+1];
                                     }
                                  key[y] = '\0';
                               }
                               key[x] = tolower(key[x]);
                            }

                            printf("Key text:\n%s\n", key);
                            fclose( file );
    }

    char* fname2 = argv[ 2 ];
    FILE *file2 = fopen( fname2, "r" );
    char plain[512];
    int j,k, l=0;


    if ( file2 == 0)
    {
       printf("Could not open file\n");
    }else {
       printf("File opened successfully\n");

                      while(!feof(file2))
                         {
                            fscanf(file2, "%c", &plain[l]);
                            l++;
                         }fscanf(file2, "%c", &plain[l]);
                           /* for(j=0; key[j] != '\0'; j++)
                            {
                               while(!((plain[j] >= 'a' && plain[j] <= 'z') || (plain[j] >= 'A' && plain[j] <= 'Z') || plain[j] == '\0'))
                               {
                                  for(k=j; plain[k] != '\0'; ++k)
                                     {
                                       plain[k]=plain[k+1];
                                     }
                                  plain[k] = '\0';
                               }
                               plain[j] = tolower(plain[j]);
                            }*/

                            printf("Plain text:\n%s\n", plain);
                            fclose(file2);
    }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: [why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Answer (score 1):

**[feof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/)**

> Check end-of-file indicator
>   Checks whether the end-of-File indicator associated with stream is set, returning a value different from zero if it is.
>
> This indicator is generally set by a previous operation on the stream that attempted to read at or past the end-of-file.
>
> **Notice that stream's internal position indicator may point to the end-of-file for the next operation, but still, the end-of-file indicator may not be set until an operation attempts to read at that point.**
>   *[emphasis mine]*

Now, lets see the how this loop will work:

```
                      while(!feof(file))
                     {
                        fscanf(file, "%c", &key[z]);
                        z++;
                     }fscanf(file, "%c", &key[z]);
```

Assume that `fscanf()` has read the last character of file. After this, the stream internal position indicator is pointing to EOF but `feof()` will return `0` because there is no read operation attempted on the stream which will set the end-of-file indicator. Hence the control go inside the loop and `fscan()` will attempt to read from `file`. Since EOF is reached, `fscan()` will set the end-of-file indicator. Now the `EOF` is set, so the `feof()` will return non-zero value and loop will end. Hence, the way you are using `feof()`, you will always have this extra iteration of `while` loop.
After encountering EOF, you are still trying to read from stream `file`:

```
fscanf(file, "%c", &key[z]);
```

Here, also `fscanf()` will return the `EOF` because there is nothing remain to read from stream `file`. This statement is meaning less.

In C, strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters terminated by a null character `\0`. `fscanf()` does not automatically append null character at the end when you read from stream using `%c` format specifier. So, the character array `key` and `plain` does not have null character at the end of characters read and if you try to print them using `%s`, you may get some junk character's in the output.

You can do:

```
while ((ret = fscanf(file, "%c", &key[z])) != EOF) {
    z++;
}
key[z] = '\0';
```

You can also read the string of characters from `file` using `%s` format specifier, like this:

```
fscanf(file, "%511s", key);
```

With `%s` format specifier you dont need loop and a terminating null character is automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.

It is good to add check for max character modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer (which is `511`, in your case).

Alternatively, you can also use `fgets()` to read from file.

---

Check this:

[while ( !feof (file) ) is always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)
[Reading from file using fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434207/reading-from-file-using-fgets)

Comment: Very well done with the `feof` and *nul-termination* explanation.