# Why cannot I read string by fgets in C programming language?

Tags: c, file, fgets

I have this code work :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
     FILE *File_fp = fopen("Example.dat", "w");
     char Temporary[50];
     if(!File_fp)
     {
        printf("An error occurred while creating the file.\n");
        exit(1);
     }

     fprintf(File_fp, "This is an example.\n");
     fgets(Temporary, 49, File_fp);

     printf("It was \"%s\"\n", Temporary);
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

I printed "This is an example." in the file, "Example.dat" and I want to read it again from the file by code above but there's no string in the output. Why? Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading from file using fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434207/reading-from-file-using-fgets)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your solution solved my problem.

Comment: @AmirMohsenGhasemi Feel free to accept the made answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a file, you have to use the mode "r". Example: 
`FILE *File_fp = fopen("Example.dat", "r");`

And you made a mistake in this code. If it fails to create a file, *fopen()* function will return *NULL*. Then the value of the file pointer would be *NULL*.
So, in your code *if section* will execute when the file is successfully created. So, change your code like this:

```
if(File_fp)
 {
  printf("An error occurred while creating the file.\n");
  exit(1);
 }
```

Just remove the **(!) logical not** sign.

Comment: The second part of your answer is incorrect — `if (File_fp)` is equivalent to `if (File_fp != NULL)`.  _That_ is the inverted test; the code in the question is correct, albeit inscrutable.  I always write `if (File_fp == NULL)` which doesn't leave much room for misinterpretation.

Comment: Oh shit! I've made a mistake. Thanks for informing that. @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 3):

You are opening the file in write-only mode ("w"). Use "w+" for reading and writing.

```
FILE *File_fp = fopen("Example.dat", "w+");
```

Comment: Have you set the pointer to the beginning of the file before reading?

Comment: Note that if you have an update stream, you must use a positioning operation (such as `fseek()` or `rewind()`) between a write operation and a read operation, and also between a read operation that did not encounter EOF and a write operation.  Plus, the program will not be able to read what it just wrote; the file position is after what was written, so a seek operation would be necessary to find what was written.